# Hover p element to show div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a div become visible when I hover a p element, and I've tried using the answers from similar questions to no success. I think the problem maybe lies in that I used a solution for a typographic problem that might not be ideal... Anyway, here is the code:

HTML

```
<div class="priser">
<p id="price_list"><div id="image1"></div>
FRISYRKLIPPNING & STYLING</p>
</div>
<div class="priser2">
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="letter-spacing:2px">FRÅN 449KR</span></p>
```

CSS

```
.priser {
    top: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "helveticaneueltstd ltcn";
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    left: 300px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom:130px;
    cursor: default;
}

.priser2 {
    top: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: "helveticaneueltstd ltcn";
    letter-spacing: 220px;
    left: 300px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: default;
}

#image1 {
position: fixed;
top: 220px;
width: 360px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -180px;
display: none;
background-image: url(../images/MSH%20KLAR/Toppklippning%20med%20styling.png);
}

.price_list:hover #image1 {
display:block;
}
```

Comment: It should be `#price_list` since it's a `id` - not a class.

Answer (score 2):

You have .price_list (a class) when price_list is the ID of the p element.

Change it to:

```
#price_list:hover #image1 {
```

Comment: Haha, didn't see that. It's still not working though.

Comment: The element has no content and no height. Give it one or the other.